# How to parse json data using jq?

Tags: linux, json, jq

I need to fetch below objects from json which I am getting via API. I am trying with jq which is available on ubuntu 16.04.
I am trying to get data in this format `device_name C:|` `free 18707755008.0` `total_size   55832473600.0`

Any suggest how should i approach on this ? The goal is get above 3 object in excel.

```
{
    "logical": {
        "D:|": {
            "device_name": [
                "D:\\"
            ],
            "used_percent": [
                52.6,
                "%"
            ],
            "fstype": "NTFS",
            "free": [
                10178084864.0,
                "B"
            ],
            "total_size": [
                21471686656.0,
                "B"
            ],
            "used": [
                11293601792.0,
                "B"
            ],
            "opts": "rw,fixed"
        },
        "C:|": {
            "device_name": [
                "C:\\"
            ],
            "used_percent": [
                66.5,
                "%"
            ],
            "fstype": "NTFS",
            "free": [
                18707755008.0,
                "B"
            ],
            "total_size": [
                55832473600.0,
                "B"
            ],
            "used": [
                37124718592.0,
                "B"
            ],
            "opts": "rw,fixed"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following outputs 2 lines with a string format seen on the last line you can easily change:

```
jq -M -r '.[] | keys[] as $var |
 [.[$var].free[0], .[$var].total_size[0]] as [$f,$t] |
 "device_name \($var) free \($f) total_size \($t)" '
```

output:

```
device_name C:| free 18707755008 total_size 55832473600
device_name D:| free 10178084864 total_size 21471686656
```

Comment: I get error `jq -M -r '.[] | keys[] as $var | [.[$var].free[0], .[$var].total_size[0]] as [$f,$t] | "device_name \($var) free \($f) total_size \($t)" ' disk.json`
**error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '$'
.[] | keys[] as $var | [.[$var].free[0], .[$var].total_size[0]] as [$f,$t] | "device_name \($var) free \($f) total_size \($t)"                                                                    1 compile error**

Comment: I am using jq 1.5. What does `jq --version` say?

Comment: `jq -V` `jq-1.4-1-e73951f` for this it doesn't works
`jq -V` `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe` for this version it works

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
jq '.logical["D:|"].free[0], .logical["D:|"].total_size[0]' file.json
```

### Output:

```
10178084864
21471686656
```

Comment: This works but in json data the drives can be from a to z.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the device names from the `device_name` key's value under `logical` rather than from the keys directly under `logical` (this makes it easier and also gives you a value that is a valid device name on Windows systems), and that you also want what I believe is the *unit of measurement* attached to the actual numbers (would make sense if there is a chance that you might have variable units in the data):

```bash
jq -r '
    ["Device name", "Free space", "Total size"],
    (
        .logical[] |
        [
            .device_name[0],
            (.free       | map(tostring) | add),
            (.total_size | map(tostring) | add)
        ]
    ) | @csv' file.json
```

Given the data in the question in `file.json`, this would generate the following CSV document (which would be trivial to import into Excel):

```
"Device name","Free space","Total size"
"D:\","10178084864B","21471686656B"
"C:\","18707755008B","55832473600B"
```

Change each of the two calls to `add` into `join(" ")` if you want to have a space between the number and the unit.